# When Was My Property Released After Segue?

Tags: objective-c, memory

I have a view controller `AViewController`, who contains a property called `item`. In the `prepareForSegue` method, `item` creates a new object using `[[SomeObject alloc] init]`. I found that `item` is always `nil` before it creating the new object when `prepareForSegue` is called.

The question is, I never released `item`, when was it become `nil`???

**Here's the code:**

```
@interface AViewController : UIViewController
@property SomeObject * item;
@end

@implementation AViewController
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
  if(self.item == nil) {
     NSLog(@"item is nil.");
  }
  self.item = [[SomeObject alloc] init];
}
@end
```

`item` is always `nil` even when `prepareForSegue` is called more than once.

Comment: You'll need to post your code.

Comment: I'm not sure what's the default for a property, but you should make it explicit that it's strong. `@property (nonatomic, strong) SomeObject *item`

Comment: @EmilioPelaez thanks. with `(nonatomic, strong)` `item` was still released.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are performing a segue from AViewController to SomeDestinationController?  If so, when your segue completes and SomeDestinationController is visible your "item" object that you created on AViewController has been released.

Comment: Yes. `item` is visible to `SomeDestinationController`. I've tested that `item` will be released after the segue. So typically any objects visible to `SomeDestinationController` will be released if they are created during the segue? I'm from `C++` so kind of confused why the object I created was not released by me..